# Unexpected error on ACDOAuthSigner connection

Tags: ios, ios5, acaccount

Has anyone gotten this exception before? If so, what does it mean? I get this occasionally when trying to save a new account to an ACAccountStore. So far I haven't been able to find any information as to what the problem is.

```
'Unexpected error on ACDOAuthSigner connection: Error Domain=XPCObjectsErrorDomain Code=2'
```

Comment: I just happen to get a report with the same clueless information. I don't save accounts, just read them.